# Unexpected sort order in de_DE.UTF-8 locale using the flag -f of the sort cmd

Tags: sort, locale, unicode

While sorting in the following environment:

```
$ uname -a
Linux srap12dxR1 3.12.28-4-default #1 SMP Thu Sep 25 17:02:34 UTC 2014 (9879bd4) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ env | egrep 'LANG|LC'
LC_COLLATE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8
```

the following UTF-8 encoded file:

```
$ cat sort_me 
¬B
b
Ä
D
X
ä
C
c
A
a
$ od -c sort_me 
0000000 302 254   B  \n   b  \n 303 204  \n   D  \n   X  \n 303 244  \n
0000020   C  \n   c  \n   A  \n   a  \n
```

using the *-f* flag (fold to upper case) I get:

```
A
a
b
C
c
D
X
¬B
Ä
ä
```

i.e. the char *¬* is not ignored and the German Umlaut *Ä ä* are placed at the end.

Not using the flag *-f* the output is semingly correct:

```
$ sort sort_me
a
A
ä
Ä
b
¬B
c
C
D
X
```

i.e. the char *¬* is ignored and *¬B* is sorted below the char *b*, but why the German Umlauts are not just treated as beeing normal chars as the Wiki states:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order 
"...In German letters with umlaut (Ä, Ö, Ü) are treated generally just like their non-umlauted versions,..."